# The approximation of the solution of Riccati equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

One form of the Riccati equation is the following ODE:

$$
y''(t)+K(t)y(t)=0.
$$
We assume that $y(t)$ with $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$ is a solution of the above equation.

If we set $z(t)=\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)}$, then we have
$$
z'(t)+z^2(t)+K(t)=0.
$$

My question is, if $K(t)$ has some decaying property, say $K(t)=t^{-k}$ for all large $t$, can we have a decaying estimate for $z(t)$? More precisely, can we find a constant $c(k)>1$ such that
$$
z(t)=t^{-1}+O(t^{-c(k)})?
$$
Moreover, what is the dependence of $c(k)$ on $k$?

Comment: If at $k(t)\sim{t^{-k}}$ at $t>>1$ you would have $y(t)\sim\sqrt{t}Z_{-\frac{1}{k+2}}\Big(-2(k+2)t^{-\frac{1}{2(k+2)}}\Big)$, where $Z_{l}(x)=J_{l}(x)+Y_{l}(x)$ is a cyllindrical function

Answer (score 0):

In the question :

if $K(t)$ has some decaying property, say $K(t)=t^{-k}$ for all large $t$, can we have a decaying estimate for $z(t)$?

It is implicitly supposed that $z(t)$ is decaying.

This supposition is not always true. They are some cases where $z(t)$ is not decaying for $t\to\infty$ even if $K(t)$ is decaying.

A very simple example is shown below. In case of $K(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ which is decaying for $t\to\infty$ , the exact solution is 
$$y(t)=2\sqrt{t}J_1(2\sqrt{t})$$
$$z(t)=\frac{J_0(2\sqrt{t})+\frac{J_1(2\sqrt{t}) }{\sqrt{t}}-J_2(2\sqrt{t}) }{2\sqrt{t}J_1(2\sqrt{t}) }$$
$$t\to\infty\qquad z(t)=-\tan\left(2\sqrt{t}+\frac{\pi}{4} \right)+O\left(\frac{1}{t^{1/4}} \right)$$
The main term of the asymptotic expansion of $z(t)$ is not decaying.

Moreover it alternatively goes to $\pm\infty$.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]